# Invariant factors and the elementary divisors of the group $(\mathbb{Z}/77 \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, ideals, finite-rings

> Find the invariant factors and the elementary divisors of the group $(\mathbb{Z}/77 \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$.

I have shown that $(\mathbb{Z}/77 \mathbb{Z})^{\times} \cong  \mathbb{Z}/10 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/6 \mathbb{Z}$. I am stuck on this problem. Could anyone help me at this point?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* By the Chinese remainder theorem,
$$
C_{10} \cong C_2 \times C_5,
\qquad
C_{6} \cong C_2 \times C_3
$$
Rearrange and recombine. This gives the elementary divisors
$$
C_2 \times C_2 \times C_3 \times C_5
$$
and the invariant factors 
$$
C_2 \times (C_2 \times C_3 \times C_5) \cong C_2 \times C_{30}
$$ and

Comment: Which theorem allow us to affirm this fact?

Comment: I found as elementary divisors $2^2$, $3$ and $5$. Do you know what are the invariant factors? ... how to find out the values?

Comment: you should have 2,2,3,5 not 2^2,3,5, i.e. the exponents matter.  once you have the elementary divisors correct, each with correct exponent, there is only one way to arrange their relatively prime products to successively divide each other.  that gives the invariant factors.